# FullCalendar not displaying events on the calendar interface

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

FullCalendar is not displaying the events on the interface even though the format for **(events) as a json feed** is correct. Below is an example of the array from which I feed in the events to the calendar. I am also able to get the data on the console, indicating that the api is returning with the events correctly, it is just not populating on the interface. What can be causing this issue?

```
[
  {
    "title": "Football game",
    "start": "2021-06-08T06:00:00",
    "end": "2021-06-08T07:00:00"
  },
  {
    "title": "Catch up call",
    "start": "2021-06-09T00:00:00",
    "end": "2021-06-09T02:00:00"
  }
]
```

***Below is the code where i am initiating and rendering the calendar***

```
    let $calendar = $('.calendar-display')
    

    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
      plugins: [dayGridPlugin,timeGridPlugin],
      events: "../apis/calendar",
      initialView: "timeGridWeek",
      allDaySlot: false,
      slotEventOverlap: false
      
    });
    
  var start = "6/6/2021"
  var end = "6/13/2021"

  retrieveData(start,end)

  function retrieveData(start, end) {
          let configData = {start: start, end: end};
    
          console.log(configData)

          $.ajax({

            method: 'GET',
            url: "../apis/calendar",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: configData,
            success: function (data) {

              console.log(data)
              calendar.render()
              
            },
            error: function (error) {
              console.log("error here",error);
            }
          })
        };

  });

  calendar.render()
}
```

***The response in console***

[image]

***Api call in network tools***

[image]

***It returns a null array for the fullCalendar ajax request, even though it is pointing to the same endpoint***

[image]

Comment: If you're trying to use the events as a JSON feed approach then you seem to have misunderstood it significantly. Try must putting `events: '../apis/calendar'` as an option in the fullCalendar setup. fullCalendar should then handle the rest, you shouldn't need to write your own Ajax request - that's the whole point of that approach (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-json-feed).

Comment: P.s. none of the code you wrote ever passes any event data to fullCalendar, there's no reason to have any expectation that it would show any events. It's unclear what part of the code you thought was doing that. You wrote `events: calendarEndpoint` but `calendarEndpoint` appears to be an undefined variable.

Comment: @ADyson I have edited the question above, calendarEndpoint variable infact pointed to '../apis/calendar' but for ease of understanding I have removed the variable and directly added the url now. Additionaly, earlier was able to get the events on the interface when running on localhost, when I deploy it to azure, it stops showing the events on the interface.

Comment: Ok I see. and what have you done to debug that? Any issues in the browser console or network tools? Any server side issues in the azure app (or whatever the endpoint is served by)?

Comment: No issues on the browser console and network tools. It make the request as expected and gets the response as expected. It's simply not displaying on the interface.

Comment: I have added in the screenshots for your reference. for both network tools and response in the console.

Comment: From the screenshot you can see two calls to the endpoint in your network tool - one from fullCalendar and one from your custom Ajax call below it. Look at the raw responses to each one - are they both identical? You've only shown the console log from your second request. Actually click on each call in the network tool and go to its response tab

Comment: How can I check for the raw response for the first request (i.e. from fullCalendar)?

Comment: They're both the same - [{"title":"Football game","start":"2021-06-08T06:00:00","end":"2021-06-08T07:00:00"},{"title":"Town Hall Meeting","start":"2021-06-09T00:00:00","end":"2021-06-09T02:00:00"}]

Comment: The response from the fullCalendar request is an empty array surprisingly, and for my custom Ajax request is the array as shown above. So, they're both different. What could be the reason for this? When I run it on localhost, then theyre identical

Comment: I have added in the screenshot of the FullCalendar ajax response in the question above. It's a null array. However, for my custom ajax request it returns me with the correct array. What could be causing this? They both point to the same endpoint

Comment: Well if you notice from the network screenshot, the content of the requests is different. fullCalendar sends the start and end dates in yyyy-mm-dd format, whereas your request sends them in mm/dd/yyyy format. Maybe your server-side code is mis-interpreting the dates fullCalendar sends? If it works locally then maybe it's a config difference between local and server, at a guess. (Also your screenshot shows the custom request using `startDate` and `endDate` instead of `start` and `end`, although that's not what your code shows would happen, so presumably you've deployed a different version.

Comment: If I was you though, I would change the server code so it accepts dates in yyyy-mm-dd format in all cases. mm/dd/yyyy could be open to mis-interpretation - it's hard to be sure if 06/03/2021 is supposed to be 3rd June or 6th March for example, because dd/mm/yyyy is also a very common date format. yyyy-mm-dd is the ISO format, accepted universally and unambiguous. Make your server read dates in that format and I expect the problem would be solved easily.

Comment: Also, another thing sorry - the fullCalendar request you showed is asking for dates from 2021-06-13 to 2021-06-20, whereas your custom request goes from 2021-06-06 to 2021-06-13. Those are different time periods, so it's not even a fair comparison. If you're going to do a test, make it use the same data in both cases! So maybe the issue is even simpler - perhaps there are no events between 2021-06-13 and 2021-06-20 in your database? I can't say for sure, because I cannot see your data or your server-side code.

Comment: Got it, I will try implementing this and let you know! Thanks! :)